# How to POST request in c# with content-type being x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, http-post, access-token, postman

[Picture of Postman POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIxZ2.png)

I would like to make this POST request to receive an OAuth2 access token but using c# code in Visual Studio 2015.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Net.HttpWebRequest` is the class you need to know, this is a easy sample. About more infomation see MSDN :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
webRequest.Timeout = 20 * 1000;
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36";


//write the data to post request
//Postdata : a=1&b=2&c=3
byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Postdata);
if (buffer != null)
{
     webRequest.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
     webRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}

WebResponse wr = webRequest.GetResponse()
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesnt work at the moment. How would you write out the Postdata with the type being x-www-form-url-encoded? As a string format or dictionary or list? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: See the note `Postdata` is a string `Postdata : a=1&b=2&c=3`